# Array.prototype vs [] perf

Tags: javascript, performance

Quick question that I haven't really had a chance to look into. Which is more performant when used in a call/apply sort of context: `Array.prototype` vs `[]`?

e.g.:

```
function test1() {
    return Array.prototype.splice.apply(arguments, [1, 2]);
}

test1([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);

function test2() {
    return [].splice.apply(arguments, [1, 2]);
}

test1([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
```

My thoughts: I would assume the `Array.prototype` way is more performant because a prototype function can be reused and no literal need be created. Not really sure though.

Using JSPerf (with chrome) it looks like the `Array.prototype` is indeed slightly more performant:

http://jsperf.com/array-perf-prototype-vs-literal

Comment: I would expect the `Array.prototype.splice` to be quicker for the reason you listed; there is no extra object creation. However, this is a micro-optimization at best, and you should focus on readability in these situations.

Comment: *agreed* Which is more readable in your opinion? I'd lean to Array.prototype but keep seeing [] used in libs etc.

Comment: I would agree with `Array.prototype` on the face of it as well, although Dpolehonski makes a good point in his answer about the reduction in bytes when using `[]`. I think the benefits of either approach are so minor, that it boils down to personal preference more than anything else.

Comment: Try [revision 3](http://jsperf.com/array-perf-prototype-vs-literal/3), which really acts on the arguments object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the browser running it. In chrome it seems .prototype is faster, firefox shows no difference between the two although generally performs slower than chrome. IE9 shows a big speed increase for .prototype but is the slowest browser by far.

However, this sort of optimization is so small that one could argue the time saved is offset against the extra bytes required to read the code. I digress though, If these are the biggest performance issues your coming against then you really don't have any problems with optimization!

EDIT:

I added an extra test [here](http://jsperf.com/array-perf-prototype-vs-literal/2) where I used the array passed into the function to call the splice function which showed up as faster than both in both IE, Chrome and Firefox.
My conclusion, if you already have the array handy, use it, else use the prototype.

Comment: Thanks guys really helpful comments! The array fn cache idea is clever. I tried the revisions in different browsers and also came to the same conclusion, it depends on the browser JS engine. Also, agreed about micro optimization. Most of my perf issues come from DOM interactions ..