# Value of directly accessing prototype i.e. Object.prototype.toString.call()

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is there a reason for referencing a method directly from the prototype rather than via inheritance? These seem to be de facto standards:

```
var argsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

and

```
var isArr = Object.prototype.toString.call(object) === '[object Array]';
```

A literal seems better to me? It's shorter and less confusing to read.

```
var argsArr = [].slice.call(arguments);
```

and

```
var isArr = {}.toString.call(object) === '[object Array]';
```

If there's a performance gain, it must be negligible and the function is easily cached. Maybe there's a tiny overhead in creating a new object but again that is negligible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array.prototype vs \[\] perf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577533/array-prototype-vs-perf)

Comment: Not specifically a performance question. There must be a reason that the former code is so prevalent.

Comment: To me it's shorter but more confusing. Also, the explicit `.prototype` access is indeed a [little faster](http://jsperf.com/array-perf-prototype-vs-literal/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way would work perfectly well, of course. It does create and throw away objects unnecessarily, but as you say, the overhead of that would be incredibly trivial. FWIW, the readability thing is subjective (I find the version using the prototype easier to read.)

I think it's mostly just a desire to avoid that unnecessary creation, the unnecessary memory churn. Engines used to be a lot slower than they are now.

*Engaging premature-micro-optimization mode...*

[Looks like](http://jsperf.com/slice-from-proto-rather-than-temp) for the `slice` use-case, on Chrome using a literal is about 4% slower on my machine, on Firefox it's more lke 9%, with no difference at all on IE10. Very likely whatever you're doing after that will swamp that effect. Of course, the effects from memory churn are harder to measure.

If you're doing this a lot, I would just bypass the whole issue and have a `Utils` object (or add these to `Array`):

```
var Utils = (function() {
    var arraySlice = Array.prototype.slice;      // Or [].slice
    var objToString = Object.prototype.toString; // Or {}.toString

    function cloneArray(a) {
        return arraySlice.call(a);
    }

    function isArray(a) {
        return objToString.call(a) === '[object Array]';
    }

    return {
        cloneArray: cloneArray,
        isArray:    isArray
    };
})();
```

Comment: But `Array.prototype.slice === [].slice` and I don't see how it could be overriden to give different results when called on `arguments`.

Comment: You have explained the reason to call Arrays `slice` on `arguments`   while OP asks if one method of calling `slice` (`Array.prototype.slice`) is superior to another (`[].slice`).